# How to select an unordered list in selenium C# .. Not able to catch

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to find the ul id "mainTimeSheet" and li item weekly report by id = timesheetReport but not getting it.
I am new to C# selenium.

Below is the code i am trying in C# :

```
//var drop = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@id='mainTimeSheet']"));

var drop = driver.FindElement(By.Id("mainTimeSheet")).
               FindElement(By.XPath(".//li[@id='timesheetReport']"));


drop.Click();
```

HTML Code:

```
 <li class="dropdown">
 <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
 target="#mainTimeSheet">
   <i class="fa fa-fw fa-tasks"></i>&nbsp; Time Sheet <span class="fa 
 arrow"></span>
 </a>
  <ul id="mainTimeSheet" class="nav nav-second-level collapse">

    <li>
      <a id="timesheetReport" href="/ShaeetsListsadas.aspx"><i 
 class="fa fa-fw fa-tasks"></i>&nbsp; Weekly Report</a>
     </li>
    <li>
       <a id="submitTimeSheet" href="/SheetsFormsads.aspx"><i 
 class="fa fa-fw fa-tasks"></i>&nbsp; Submit Timesheet</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="timeSheetDetailReport" href="/sheetsReportsasd.aspx"<i 
class="fa fa-fw fa-tasks"> 
 </i>&nbsp; Day Wise Report</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

**Xpath to check:**

```
//li//a[@id='timesheetReport']
```

If it shows 1/1 matching node then

click it like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement timeSheet = wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@id='mainTimeSheet']")));
timeSheet.Click();

IWebElement weeklyReport= wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.XPath("//li//a[@id='timesheetReport']")));
weeklyReport.Click();
```

**Update:**

to resolve  `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException:`

You should debug your code like below:

1. Make sure the browser is launched in full screen using

   ```
   driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
   ```
2. Use `ActionChains`:

   ```
   Actions actionProvider = new Actions(driver);
   actionProvider.MoveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(e => e.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@id='mainTimeSheet']")))).Click().Build().Perform();
   ```
3. Use `ExecuteScript`:

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
   IWebElement timeSheet = wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@id='mainTimeSheet']")));
   ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click(); ", timeSheet);
   ```

Comment: Thanks @cruisepandey , I have checked the node and it's matched but still it's not working.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the dropdown in the question, can you please take a look, we need to click on it first to expand the dropdown.

Comment: Can you tell me the steps? First we will have to click on Timesheet and then to weekly report? If that so, can you share HTML of both the tags ?

Comment: Yes that is the case.

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check above and make sure for both the XPath we should have unique entry in HTMLDOM.

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Comment: I have added the HTML code in question.

Comment: Both the XPath have unique entries but don't know where is the issue, anyways thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Not sure for which element you are getting elementNotInteractable exception, however a common way to solve this exception is updated above.

Comment: How are we doing here? Did it help ?

Comment: No, the solution you provided is not working i am trying but still no success.

Comment: okay, and what is the output of action class and execute script code that I have provided here? was there any error? if so, let me know

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable still same error.

Comment: I have added an image of the side bar, actually control is not going over Timesheet button. I have bypassed this step and directly opened the Submit Timesheet link all other operations are working fine but this step is not working.